# Vagrant & VMWare Fusion Communication Failure after Mac Monterey 12.5.1 Update

Tags: vagrant, macos-monterey, vmware-fusion, vagrant-plugin

I use Vagrant to boot, configure and run my development environment (see vagrant file detail below)

I am receiving the following error in vagrant following a Mac OS (Monterey 12.5.1) update overnight:

> Vagrant encountered an unexpected communications error with the
> Vagrant VMware Utility driver. Please try to run the command
> again. If this error persists, please contact support@hashicorp.com

**Does anyone know what could cause this specifically?  I believe the Utility is driving the issue but I'm uncertain how to track it down and clearly identify the cause.**

I'll try to lay out my setup as simply as possible using a Macbook Pro (M1 Core - Arm64) Running Monterey 12.5.1 and guidance from the following [Vagrant and VMWare Tech Preview on Apple M1 Pro](https://gist.github.com/sbailliez/f22db6434ac84eccb6d3c8833c85ad92)

- Install Rosetta via:

  /usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
- Vagrant 2.3.0 (also tried 2.2.18)
- VMware Fusion Technology Preview 21H1 (for ARM)
- Simlink Generate via:

  ln -s /Applications/VMWare\ Fusion\ Tech\ Preview.app /Applications/VMWare\ Fusion.app
- Vagrant VMWare Utility (https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant-vmware-utility/1.0.21/vagrant-vmware-utility_1.0.21_x86_64.dmg)
- Utility installed with:

  vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop

This was all working well prior to the update using the following Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vbguest.auto_update = false

  config.vbguest.no_remote = true
  config.vm.box = "uwbbi/bionic-arm64"
  config.vm.hostname = "mywebsite"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.7"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1080, host: 1080

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/app-cake2", #, :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=766"]
     id: "mywebsite",
     group:'vagrant',      
     owner:'www-data',
     umask: "755"

  config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v, override|
     v.memory = 512
  end
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled using these instructions (and a few variations) with no success as of the time of this post.

Any suggestions or recommendations are appreciated in advance.

I tried to be as complete as possible but if you see something I've omitted please comment and I'll add.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Comment: Hi Rob, I'm happy to take the question there, but I suspect the conflict might have something to do with the vagrant-plugin which I believe is open-source managed now.  If you feel that assumption is/was in error, please confirm. Thanks!